# Edge dissolve impossible - How to get the same error message by script than by the original Blender operator?

Tags: python, scripting

I try to perform a edge dissolve by script. Some dissolve operations are impossible. And then you get a error message. The problem is that i get a big error message with all the bells and whistles when i do this by script. But when i use the edge dissolve from the Blender delete menu then i just get a short string that this operation is impossible.

How can i stop the big error message, and display the short string instead?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can [catch the error and report it](https://gist.github.com/p2or/68e43e1909e08ae48ff343039afa7ce7) (but might be overkill).

Comment: Works like charm. You should make your comment an answer :)

Comment: Quirk detected ^^ . My selection is gone after error report. Is there a way to get selection back? Or to prevent that the mesh gets deselected? The script doesn't seem to perform a script action for it, but yet the geometry is deselected then.

Comment: Nevermind, was me being stupid.